# Pdf not scrolling with iframe in webview

Tags: android

Pdf file not scrolling in `webview`. I use iFrame for show pdf in `webview` but don't understand why it is not scrolling. It works when clicks on scrollview only.

my code is:-

```
 fetchholder.webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                fetchholder.webView1.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                fetchholder.webView1.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                fetchholder.webView1.loadUrl(doc);
                fetchholder.webView1.loadData(doc ,  null,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

At first check if you have scrollview enabled in the webview container. If it is enabled then check if scrollview works for another sites. If that is OK too, then may be your sites's probelm which you want to show.